# How to play a specific frequency sound?

Tags: reactjs, audio, native, frequency, emitter

So I'm trying to find something to help me out but without much luck. I'm trying to click a button and start a specific frequency for example 160hz but can't figure it out yet, if anyone has any experience or can help out with this, please let me know.
Thank you!

I tried react-native-frequency, but it's deprecated now and looking for other alternatives